# Is it possible to log webcontent change as audit event?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a requirement in which the events such as profile change and webcontent change need to be logged as audit events. For profile change, audit log is generated. For webcontent change,I want to know whether it is possible to generate audit log. I have seen some projects with liferay hook for page change audit logs. But our project is not a liferay hook project. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide code (as [mcve]) of what you have done so far, expectations, observations. And more details, e.g. on the (exact) version. As it is, the answer to the title is "yes" and for "how to proceed" is too broad to be on-topic for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Liferay has a history of records for the JournalArticle. I don't know if that is exactly your requirement. In my experience, a hook is the best way for this.

The other solution is to implement listener on the submit form, when the content is edited. But in both cases, liferay must be modified.